# Use Java to Parse XML for Specific Element

Tags: java, xml-parsing

I'm receiving the below xml response and I need to parse so that all I get is Collection of the URL128 xml Element values.  Any ideas on the most efficient way to accomplish this in Java?

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <imagesXML>
        <Images>
            <Image>
                <ImageUID Scope="Public" Type="Guid" Value="{7f2535d0-9a41-4997-9694-0a4de569e6d9}"/>
                <CorbisID Scope="Public" Type="String" Value="42-15534232"/>
                <Title Scope="Public" Type="String" Value="Animal"/>
                <CreditLine Scope="Public" Type="String" Value="¬© Robert Llewellyn/Corbis"/>
                <IsRoyaltyFree Scope="Public" Type="Boolean" Value="False"/><AspectRatio Scope="Public" Type="String" Value="1.500000"/>
                <URL128 Scope="Public" Type="String" Value="http://cachens.corbis.com/CorbisImage/thumb/15/53/42/15534232/42-15534232.jpg"/>
            </Image>
            <Image>
                <ImageUID Scope="Public" Type="Guid" Value="{7f2535d0-9a41-4997-9694-0a4de569e6d9}"/>
                <CorbisID Scope="Public" Type="String" Value="42-15534232"/>
                <Title Scope="Public" Type="String" Value="Animal"/>
                <CreditLine Scope="Public" Type="String" Value="¬© Robert Llewellyn/Corbis"/>
                <IsRoyaltyFree Scope="Public" Type="Boolean" Value="False"/><AspectRatio Scope="Public" Type="String" Value="1.500000"/>
                <URL128 Scope="Public" Type="String" Value="http://cachens.corbis.com/CorbisImage/thumb/15/53/42/15534232/42-15534232.jpg"/>
            </Image>
        </Images>
    </imagesXML>
```

Comment: if thats all the xml then SAX would okay but I always ask people to look at groovy xmlslurper

Comment: By 'efficient', do you mean fast, or do you mean least effort/code? If fast, I might recommend SAX or StAX parsing (or even custom parsing just to get at that one element). If least effort, then DOM parsing or even a 3rd-party lib that provides XPath evaluation.

Comment: least effort in coding without majorly sacrificing performance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Java XPath API is simple to use:

```
String xmlData = "<test><one><URL128 myAttribute='value' /></one></test>";
InputSource source = new InputSource(new StringReader(xmlData)); //or use your own input source

XPath xPath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();

NodeList list = (NodeList)xPath.evaluate("//URL128", source, XPathConstants.NODESET);
List<Element> elements = new ArrayList<Element>(list.getLength());
for (int i = 0; i < list.getLength(); i++)
{
    elements.add((Element)list.item(i));
}
```

Comment: great example prunge!  are you using javax.xml.bind.Element in your example?  I wasn't sure how to extract the date from the Collection of Element objects.  I probably have the wrong import...

Answer (score 2):

Use [SAX](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/sax/parsing.html), and implement the `startElement` method so that if the element name is "URL128", you extract the three attributes `Scope`, `Type` and `Value`, store them in a custom object, and add this object to a `List`.

It will be both easy and fast.